# Add a variable which should update every time you run through the loop Java

Tags: java, variables, loops

I need help on how do I add a variable to my code  for the program which is to output the number of people surveyed in the report. Use a new variable called personCount to do this, which you should update every time you run through the loop.

I tried this way but its not working

```
  class morecoffee
{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {  
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

        int person, preference, nothing, sugar, sweetener, count, quit, personcount;

        nothing = sugar = sweetener = 0;
        int personcount=0;      
        for (;;)
    {

        System.out.println ("How do you sweeten your coffee?");
        System.out.println ("1. I don't");
        System.out.println ("2. With sugar?");
        System.out.println ("3. With sweetener?");
        System.out.println ("4. Quit");
        System.out.println (personcount + " people took the survey ");

        personcount++;
        preference = input.nextInt();


        if (preference == 1)
              nothing++; 

            else if (preference == 2)
                    sugar++;
            else if (preference == 3)
                 sweetener++;

     if (preference == 4)
        break;
    }
        System.out.println ("Survey Report");
        System.out.println ("=============");

        System.out.println (nothing + " person don't sweeten coffee");
        System.out.println (sugar + " person use sugar in coffee");
        System.out.println (sweetener + " person use sweetener in coffee");
    }   
}
```

Comment: What have  you tried? Why didnt it work? Just asking on stack overflow wont help you become a better programmer.

Comment: Just duplicate what's here for variable `sweetener`, the only difference being when to do a `++` on it

Comment: Well, you know each person said either nothing, sugar, or sweetener, so you could combine those values. Or you could track the count, incrementing every time you go through the loop without breaking out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before beginning the loop write

```
int count=0;
```

and inside the loop write

```
count++;
```

This count variable will store the required value. Print it after the loop

```
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: I have edited the code like you said but it wont create a class it gives one error. 

nothing = sugar = sweetener = 0;
        int personcount=0;  
  for (;;)
    {
       
        System.out.println ("How do you sweeten your coffee?");
        System.out.println ("1. I don't");
        System.out.println ("2. With sugar?");
        System.out.println ("3. With sweetener?");
        System.out.println ("4. Quit");
  System.out.println (personcount + " people took the survey ");
        
  personcount++;
        preference = input.nextInt();

Comment: @user3499202 and try to format your comments as weel

Comment: @user3499202 you have declared the variable `personcount` twice....
see `int person, preference, nothing, sugar, sweetener, count, quit, personcount;` and `int personcount=0`

also you should provide complete error details with the code and i would advise you to use java naming conventions. and dont forget to accept the answer if it helped